# Reading AWS Param Store from Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda-edge

First foray into AWS's Lambda@Edge and trying to retrieve secrets from AWS Param Store for authentication ([following this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/signed-cookie-based-authentication-with-amazon-cloudfront-and-aws-lambdaedge-part-1-authentication/)) but getting nothing back.

Here's the function that calls the AWS.SSM function:

```
    const fromParameterStore = async(key, withDecryption = false) => {
        const { Parameter } = await ssm.getParameter({ Name: key, WithDecryption: withDecryption }).promise();
        return Parameter.Value;
    };
```

And here's how it's called from the main body of the Lambda:

```
    exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
        const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
        const testValue = fromParameterStore('my-param-key');
        console.log("test value = "+testValue);
        console.log("test value = "+JSON.stringify(testValue));
        ...
```

The output in the log is just this:

```
testvar = [object Promise]
testvar = {}
```

How can I cleanly de-reference the Promise in this case to get the actual secret out for use in the rest of the Lambda?

Thanks!

Comment: You `fromParameterStore` is asynchronous, you have to await for it: `const testValue = await fromParameterStore('my-param-key');`

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi post it as an answer :)

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi - that was it, thank you!  If you post as an answer I'll tick it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fromParameterStore` function is asynchronous, so it will return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). You will have to wait for this promise to be fulfilled, meaning you will have to use `await` when calling `fromParameterStore` function:

```
const testValue = await fromParameterStore('my-param-key');
```